# Is there an xsd schema or UML diagram for GDF and if not then why?

Tags: schema-architecture, xsd, schema

I am a GIS newbie exploring the GDF Geographic Data Files format.

The question ["GDF — Can anyone suggest some good reading?"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8632/gdf-can-anyone-suggest-some-good-reading) was a great starting point (despite dead links that have lots of dead copies on [the archive](http://web.archive.org/)), as was [this from openstreetmap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GDF) and this from [Safe, makers of FME](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/gdf/gdf.htm).

I feel it would be really useful to browse a visual UML diagram of the format (perhaps by [opening the xsd schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486758/how-to-visualize-an-xml-schema-programatically)), more or less alongside all the other reading. The best I could find so far:

1. [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/are-there-uml-models-of-the-ogc-standards-available-online-native-files-not-pdf) took me to lots of great examples for other
   formats but not GDF.
2. [This page on github](https://github.com/jetgeo/ITSGML) has the description "Information model and GML schema for GDF" but does not seem to be what I'm after. From my understanding of xsd schemas in general, I was under the impression I would be able to find a single .xsd file for the GDF format, like I was for KML, and that page does not seem to have that, unless I am failing miserably to spot it?

So is there an xsd schema for GDF and if not then why? The only reason I can think of would be that it's because it's controlled by an ISO standard - but intuitively, this doesn't stop a UML diagram, perhaps for an old version, from being publicly available?

Comment: XSD does not need to be as one file. It is common to use includes like `<include schemaLocation="itsfcm.xsd"/>`, and included schema can have more includes. Problem with ISO standards is that they are not public. I wonder if the INSPIRE schemas and datamodels coulf be usable https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/data-model/approved/r4618-ir/html/index.htm?goto=2:1:9:7:7627.